# Cypress test failing with "out of memory" error in docker

Tags: docker, cypress, aws-fargate

I have cypress tests running without any issues in local.
But when I run them in a docker container, it is failing with "out of memory" error. logs - https://pastebin.com/0TEYnfqq
I saw a suggestion in this issue(cypress-io/cypress#350) to use `--ipc=host` but the issue keeps occurring.
During the tests are running, I see RAM usage of docker container is around 1.6GB Max, but the VM on which the docker is running has around 6GB free.
I ultimately want to run these tests in AWS Fargate, any idea what is the equivalent of `--ipc=host` in fargate?
Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

"Out of memory" error you see because chrome under docker has 64MB restricted memory by default which sometimes is not enough. It has nothing about RAM. And when you run tests locally you dont have this restriction and whats why your tests are running smooth locally.
To increase this restriction run docker with 2 additional params

```
docker run -it --ipc=host --shm-size=1024M
```

docker compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  name:
    image: image_name
    environment:
      - SERVER_URL=http://server:8111
      - AGENT_NAME=docker-agent-1
      - DOCKER_IN_DOCKER=start
    privileged: true
    container_name: docker_agent_1
    ipc: host
    shm_size: 1024M
```

example of docker settings in TeamCity CI
[image]

Comment: adding `--ipc=host` didn't help, the issue was resolved when cypress tests ran using headless chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Surely using [Cypress configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Global) `numTestsKeptInMemory` could help reduce the memory consumption.

The default is "50" kept tests results (include heavy DOM snapshots); reduce it to 5 and see if that helps.